# how to conditionally display data with ejs view engine

Tags: node.js, ejs

how should i modify this code to display variable only if it's defined 
i have a variable error which represents the authentication error message

here's is my code:

```
       <% if (erreur !== '') { %>
         <div class="notif">
            <p  class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font- 
             size:16.5px;text-align:center;margin-top:-9px;color:red;">
          <b><%= error %></b></p>
         </div>
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <% if(typeof error !== 'undefined' && error){ %>
```